# Pyspark Struct columns: weird behavior after exploding

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nested

I am working with a nested json file that contains arrays on several levels that I need to explode.
I have noticed that the values in a column I created have changed after I exploded an array which is one the same level as the value I wanted to store in said column. Here is an example to visualize:

```
jsonDF = jsonDF.withColumn("values_level1", explode("data.values"))
               .withColumn("name_level1", col("values_level1.name"))
```

Until here everything is fine, column "name_level1" contains certain values that I want to filter for at a later stage. The problem begins when I continue with

```
.withColumn("values_level2", explode("values_level1.values"))
```

because now the values I had in column "name_level1" have changed and I no longer find the values I want to filter for later.

Is this something expectable which I just havent understood yet conceptually (I am rather new to Spark...)? Can I somehow "conserve" the original values in "name_level1"?

Thanks a lot in advance!

edit: I am adding a picture that might help to understand my problem:
[image]

Why does "name" change when I explode "values"?

Comment: I think you want to explode the values in the 'data'

`.withColumn("values_level2", explode("data.values"))`

values_level1 is already exploded in the first step

Comment: Hi Munesh, thanks for the reply. I do explode "data.values" in the first step and call it "values_level1". What you see on the screenshot is the structure of column "values_level1". I want to explode values_level1.values without changing values_level1.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to a colleague and he provided a solution that worked. Using

```
.withColumn("values_level2", explode_outer("values_level1.values"))
```

keeps the values I need in column "name_level1"